Augmenting data for LSTM
The problem:
I have a datset with monthly economic indicators alongside monthly stock price, containing 434 total observations.
I have attempted to fit an LSTM onto the data, but it seems to consistently overfit the data as it generates negative test $R^2$ value in conjunction with a very high training $R^2$. The model is essentially explaining less variance in the price than a horizontal line would.
Stock prediction is notoriously difficult, however I would expect the model to at least explain a small fraction of the variance in the stock price data, i.e it would generate an $R^2$ that is positive but close to $0$, because the economy does concretely affect the stock market.
My thinking is that the quantity of data is insufficient for the LSTM and is the root of the problem. My problem is that whilst I can source stock data on a daily basis, I can not do the same for the economic data. Thus, it seems I only have the data at hand to work with.
The proposed solution:
My idea was to synthetically generate daily data by applying some kind of interpolation or stochastic process on each intramonthly period and generate daily simulated data for each indicator, which I could then train the model on.
My questions:

Could this work, or would it just generate more noise for the model to overfit on?
Is there any other way in which I could realistically augment my data?
If not, is a deep learning model actually suitable for the problem domain?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Cross Validated! This seems to be related, even if it is not truly a duplicate. $//$ A horizontal line might not be such a good benchmark. I wonder what the results would be for a Campbell/Thompson pseudo $R^2$. I give additionaly details about time series pseudo $R^2$ here.


To be honest, I don't see how this would work, because you would either be feeding in noise, or information you derive from your data, but such information should already be in your model in the first place. If you are tempted to try different strategies and use the one that worked best, then all you are doing is optimizing on noise via data snooping. 2. Yes: collect more data. If that is not possible, then work with what you have. 3. Fitting an LSTM to just 434 data points is very likely to overfit. Try a standard VAR for comparison.


Thank you for your advice.
